# Custom type URL in OData

Tags: c#, odata

I'm preparing *OData service* based on [DynamicEdmModelCreation example](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation/ReadMe.txt).

Based on data types defined in my application, I'm dynamically create ***EdmEntityType*** instances - one for each type.

When root address is called, I got a list of all available collections.
Each collection consists of *name*, *kind* and *URL*. I have noticed that the name and URL are always the same.

What can I do to make custom URL address?

Instead of:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:12345/odata/anotherdatasource/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Students","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Students"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:12345/odata/anotherdatasource/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Students","kind":"EntitySet","url":"CompletelyDifferentURL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you want to look at the ODataRouteAttribute in System.Web.OData.Routing.

Comment: Could you please guide me a bit more? In DynamicEdmModelCreation example, there is only one controller with 2 actions - without any attributes defined on them. Controller is serving data for all collections.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't familiar with the DynamicEdmModelCreation - I just looked at the code on github and see your issue.  I wasn't familiar with this approach.  Since things are being dynamically defined, you would probably need to override the default $metadata as well as mess with the CustomODataRoute class.